# Removing express and http from this socket.io example

Tags: node.js, http, express, socket.io

This is the example app found on the socket.io website:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

What if I truncate it to the following, removing the instances of `http` and `express`? What difference does it make writing the app this way instead?

```
const io = require("socket.io");
const server = io.listen(3000);

server.on("connection", function(socket) {
  console.log("user connected");
  socket.emit("welcome", "welcome man");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume while connection to your port would be established, the contents of the app (currently at default `/`) would not show.